# invalid Identifier errors

Tags: oracle

So I'm trying to run these SQL tables and can not figure out why am I these list of error, any suggestions as to why am I getting these errors?

> *
> ERROR at line 8:
> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
> )
> *
> ERROR at line 9:
> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
> )
> *
> ERROR at line 13:
> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
> Description varchar2(150),
> *
> ERROR at line 3:
> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
> )
> *
> ERROR at line 6:
> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
> )
> *
> ERROR at line 7:
> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
> )
> *
> ERROR at line 11:
> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
> )
> *
> ERROR at line 9:
> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
> )
> *
> ERROR at line 9:
> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
> )
> *
> ERROR at line 8:
> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_2(
  Customer_ID int,
  Payment_ID int,
  Phone_Num int,
  Name varchar2(150),
  Address varchar2(150),
  constraint ct_PK primary key (Customer_ID)
  constraint ct_PK foreign key (Payment_ID) references Payment(Payment_ID),
);
CREATE TABLE Payment_1(
  Payment_ID int,
  Customer_ID int,
  Card_Num int,
  Experation int,
  Security_Code int,
  constraint p_PK primary key (Payment_ID),
  constraint p_PK foreign key (Customer_ID) references Customer_2(Customer_ID),
);
CREATE TABLE Plan_1(
  Plan_ID int,
  Customer_ID int,
  Employee_ID int,
  Subscription varchar2(150),
  Payment_ID int,
  DateOfPurch date,
  constraint pl_PK primary key (Plan_ID),
  constraint pl_PK foreign key (Customer_ID) references Customer_1(Customer_ID),
  constraint pl_PK foreign key (Payment_ID) references Payment_1(Payment_ID),
  constraint pl_PK foreign key (Empolyee_ID) references Employee_1(Employee_ID),
  constraint pl_PK foreign key (PK_Subscription) references Subscription_1(PK_Subscription),
);
CREATE TABLE Subscription_1(
  PK_Subscription int
  Description varchar2(150),
  Size int,
  Service_Free int,
);
CREATE TABLE Employee_1(
  Empolyee_ID int,
  Name varchar2(150),
  Telephone int,
  Address varchar2(150),
);
CREATE TABLE Inventory_1(
  type varchar2(150),
  Inventory_ID int,
  Artist_ID int,
  constraint i_PK primary key (Inventory_ID),
  constraint i_PK foreign key (Artist_ID) references Artist_1(Artist_ID),
);
CREATE TABLE Playlist_1(
  Inventory_ID int,
  Customer_ID int,
  Playlist_Name varchar2(150),
  Runtime float,
  Creation_date date,
  Number_Songs float,
  Playlist_Num int,
  constraint py_PK primary key (Inventory_ID),
  constraint py_PK foreign key (Customer_ID) references Customer_1(Customer_ID),
  );
CREATE TABLE Saved_Songs_1(
  Song_ID int,
  Song_Name varchar2(150),
  Date_Retrived  date,
  Length int,
  Album_Name varchar2(150),
  Rating float, 
  constraint s_PK primary key (Song_ID),
);
CREATE TABLE Podcast_1(
  Podcast_ID int,
  Date_Retrieved date,
  Length int,
  Episodes int,
  Rating float ,
  Cast varchar2(150),
  constraint po_PK primary key (Podcast_ID),
);
CREATE TABLE Artists_1(
  Artist_ID int,
  Name varchar2(150),
  Genre varchar2(150),
  Composition varchar2(150),
  Language varchar2(150),
  constraint a_PK primary key (Artist_ID),
);
```

Comment: You've tagged 3 conflicting RDBMS... please correct and tag only one.

Comment: Error says `ORA-00907`, it must be Oracle db

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:       constraint ct_PK primary key (Customer_ID)
The comma is missing at the end of the line.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_2(
  Customer_ID int,
  Payment_ID int,
  Phone_Num int,
  Name varchar2(150),
  Address varchar2(150),
  constraint ct_PK primary key (Customer_ID),
  constraint ct_PK foreign key (Payment_ID) references Payment(Payment_ID)
);
```

Comment: And the comma is unnecessary at the end of the foreign key lines.